# How to add this click menu in a beamer presentation that helps navigation

Tags: beamer, navigation

I'm preparing some slides for tomorrow for some students. But in my original slide I have the following click menu (marked with the red circle) but in my new slide, it's gone. How can I get it back?

[image]

Comment: Remove `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` from your code. If you don't have this line, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) because by default the symbols are present.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the navigations symbols are displayed by default. This means you somehow managed to switch them off.

Look in your code for something like `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` and remove this line to switch back to the default symbols.